# Boy's surface and normal vectors

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, projective-space

Denote by $X$ the image under the immersion $RP^2 \to R^3$ (that is, the Boy's surface). At each point $x \in X$ consider a small orthogonal segment that is centered at the point $x$. Denote by $S$ the set of all endpoints of these segments. Thus, we obtain a new surface $S$. What is this?
I think it should be $S^2$ but I cannot prove this. This construction looks like orientable double cover but there is a problem: the Boy's surface has self-intersection points (the whole curve of such points), therefore for the natural map $p: S \to X$ the preimage $p^{-1} (x)$ for any self-intersection point $x$ consists of 4 points instead of 2. So, it is not a covering or even not a ramified covering with finite number of ramification points, so we cannot use Riemann-Hurwitz formula to find the Euler characteristic of $S$. Am I missing something? How can it be done?

Comment: Note that there are infinitely many immersions from $\mathbb RP^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$. But if you're inspecting the Boy^'s surface and just shift it along normal directions by some small number $\varepsilon$ you will still have self-intersections and the resulting surface is not $S^2$.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the Boy's surface. So you're saying the surface I'm interested in is not $S^2$. But what is this?

Comment: It is just another immersion of $\mathbb RP^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$ since immersions form an open set in the $C^1$-topology.

Comment: @frog Could you explain it in the answer, please?

Answer (score 1):

Say your surface is parametrized by some smooth function $f(x,y)$ (this can be said because Boy's surface is a smooth immersion of $\mathbb RP^2$ into $\mathbb R^3$). Then you consider
$$
g_\varepsilon(x,y) = f(x,y) + \varepsilon \cdot \frac{\partial_xf(x,y)\times \partial_yf(x,y)}{\|\partial_xf(x,y)\times \partial_yf(x,y)\|}=:f(x,y) + \varepsilon \cdot n(x,y),
$$
so $g_\varepsilon$ is just a normal shift of $f$. Since $f$ is an immersion, the vector $n(x,y)$ is always defined and its length equals $1$ (and moreover, $n$ is smooth as well). Therefore you conclude that
$
g_\varepsilon - f = \varepsilon n
$
becomes arbitrarily small if $\varepsilon \to 0$. Regarding first derivatives you see that first derivatives of the difference between $g_\varepsilon - f$ are given by
$\varepsilon\cdot \partial_xn$ and $\varepsilon \cdot \partial_yn$ respectively. Again they become arbitrarily small, provided $\varepsilon \to 0$ and you conclude that $g_\varepsilon$ and $f$ are $C^1$-close. From there you get that $g$ is again an immersion since immersions form an open set in the $C^1$-topology.

Comment: I didn't really get it. It seems that you proved that if we shift our surface across normal directions then we get again $RP^2$. For example, it seems to me that you use that $n(x, y)$ is uniquely defined, but if $(x, y)$ is a self-intersection point, then we have two normal vectors. For instance, if we apply the procedure from the original question to $S^2$, the we get just a disjoint union of two spheres, here I think we should get a connected surface because of non-orientability of $RP^2$, but in your solution we didn't use it, so it also should work for $S^2$, but I think it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I didn't exactly understand then: You have well-defined normal along your immersion. If you're looking at the image you do not have a well-defined normal at self-intersection points. But then your procedure is unclear. How do you define the normal in such points? I understood that you spoke about the image but I thought you mean it in the way I got it in my answer since otherwise the procedure is not well-defined.

Comment: Let $x$ be a self-intersection point, I take two normal vectors (again, centered at the point $x$, so we have 4 endpoints). Looking at the Boy's surface, the self-intersection points are precisely the points at which two slices of our surface "meet", so we take two normal vectors that are orthogonal to these slices.

Comment: Ok, I see. But wherever two slices meet, the intersect in a certain angle (which is non-zero and different from $180^{\circ}$). But then your pushed-off slices are again gonna meet in an angle different from $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ if you only push-off by a small amount. I don't see how this procedure is avoiding self-intersections.